# Remove all the URLs (http or https) from a file

Tags: autohotkey

I have a input.txt file that I need to make a copy without all the urls (http and https) from it.

input.txt file:

```
Car Apple 1
https://www.nytimes.com

Car Apple 2
https://www.ebay.com
Car Apple 3
https://www.amazon.com

Car Apple 4
https://www.aol.com

Car Apple 5
https://www.google.com
```

What I need, output.txt:

```
Car Apple 1
Car Apple 2
Car Apple 3
Car Apple 4
Car Apple 5
```

Attempts thus far:

```
myInput:="input.txt" 
Loop, Read, %myInput%, outputFile.txt 
    If A_LoopReadLine="http"
        Continue 
    else
        FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n, output.txt 
return
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please show attempts.

Comment: myInput:="input.txt"
Loop, Read, %myInput%, outputFile.txt
If A_LoopReadLine="http"      
  Continue 
else
  FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n, output.txt
return

Answer (score 0):

```
FileRead, InputText, C:\InputText.txt
;;Reads File on location C\:InputText.txt and saves content in var InputText

;;As long as there is Car Apple [any single number] the loop goes on, use (\d{1,2}) if number goes above 9 up to 99 
while RegExMatch(InputText,"Car Apple \d") 
 {
 RegExMatch(InputText,"s)(Car Apple \d)(.*)",TextTemp)
 ;;searches for (Car Apple [any single number]) saves it in var TextTemp1 and saves the rest of the text in var TextTemp2

 InputText := TextTemp2
 ;;saves TextTemp2 values into InputText

 OutText := OutText . TextTemp1 . "`n"
 ;;concatenate values of var TextTemp1 into var OutText and adds new line at the end
 }

FileAppend, %OutText%, C:\OutText.txt
;;appends value of var OutText into C:\OutText.txt
```